# does android support only SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf in OpenSL ES?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, opensl

is SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf the only buffer queue interface supported by android openSL ES ? This interface only returns a custom pointer set during RegisterCallBack(), but there is no way to get some info as what buffer gets the callback atleast by some ID or pointer. Can someone provide some hint as to how to identify what buffer it is in the callback ?

Thanks.

Comment: The bufferqueue interface has a `GetState` function, and the state struct has an `index` member.

Comment: Thanks Michael !! That helped for this purpose as the buffers queues are played in sequence !